# How to pass text field value from Jsp page to Spring Controller without using Form Tag

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have 3 fields like `Name, Age, Address` and it has a default value that's coming from a database, now I want to edit or update each field value using the edit button, so I want to pass field edit value from jsp to spring controller.

```
<input type="text" value="${map.Fname}" id="nameEdit" disabled>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-default float-right btn-sm" value="Edit" onclick="nameEdit()">
<input type="submit" value=submit>
```

Here I have two buttons edit is for to edit the default value another submit button for to submit the value which is entered in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Form other way would be using POST call from `jQuery` or `JavaScript`

Let's assume your Rest Controller looks like this

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public void saveDetail(@RequestBody UserDetail data){

}
```

since you don't want to use form you can replace type submit with button like this

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="btnSubmit">
```

**POST call using jQuery**

```
var data = {
   "fname" : "Test",
   "lname" : "Test",
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: "application/json"
});
```

**Using JavaScript**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "url";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(json.email + ", " + json.password);
    }
};
var data = JSON.stringify(data );
xhr.send(data);
```